# Delimit range for the line $AB$, If we have tow points namely $P$

Tags: geometry

We have this hortizonal line $AB$
The shape (AB hasn't exact value):
$$A\thinspace\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}\thinspace B$$
Now we want to find the point $P$ using this rules:
$$PA=4cm$$
$$PB=3cm$$
So if we have only 2 points using those rules delimit range for $AB$.Options are:
$$1)AB<7$$
$$2)AB>1$$
$$3)1<AB<7$$
$$4)1\leq AB\leq7$$

Comment: One of the fundamental properties of a triangle is that $a+b \gt c.$

Comment: @Raptor So do you mean option 1?

Comment: @user602338 Nope, think about this problem as a triangle inequality problem, with $AB,\;PB\;PA$ as the sides.

Comment: You can $3$ inequalities with $a+b\gt c$. One of them is $\text {AB}\lt 7$. Did you consider the other two?

Comment: No i did not @Raptor!

Comment: Would you write them?

Comment: So after writing other inequalities we must choose option 3 ok @Raptor?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! Well done

Comment: You can now utilise the sane technique in all other problems of this type.